# Reproducing a paper's result for Topological Insulators

Tags: computational-physics, eigenvalues, simulation

For the past weeks I have been trying to reproduce [Agarwala's results](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00507.pdf) but I've been unsuccessful. From this paper I am trying to reproduce the first and last columns of Fig.2, by implementing eq.2; The image below is the crystalline case from the paper:

[image]

The code is made of two parts mostly: the building of the system and the method that checks which sites are connected to which. The latter method I have checked, tested and improved it and it appears to be 100% functional. The building of the system, although appears to be correct, is likely the part where the issue arises.

I have tried several things and changed the code a whole lot but the results are always incompatible with the reference. My output is:

[image]

The results are clearly different but I cannot find any issues in the code and bear in mind that since it is a crystalline structure the result are supposed to be, at least, very similar to one another.
Here's my [github](https://github.com/Crowkk/HOTI) with the code I implemented and two images: one for the crystal case and another for the random case.

Thanks in advance

PS: I was going to post this on physics exchange but apparently since it is about writing a code I am supposed to ask here.

Comment: Your question seems to be about reviewing your code, that is off-topic in this site. On the other hand, how does your result look on top of the original figure?